# What might cause Matplotlib to ignore y-axis tick locators?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime

I have a table that has two columns: a start date and a stop date. I create a range of datetime values at hour intervals between those two dates, starting at 00:00 on the starting date and ending at 23:00 on the ending date.

This is useful because I have a second table that has data for every hour and a corresponding timestamp including the date and the hour it was taken.

My code iterates through each row of the first table, matching up all the dates in the date range to their respective values in the data table. I then plot each of these one-by-one in their own subplot. If the range of times is not within the data table, I just give it all zeros.

My issue arises when I try to set the limits and the tick markers for the y-axis for each subplot. I deliberately specify I want the y-limits to be between -150 and 150, and set my tick marks at intervals of 50. When I plot this however, I get random values with various spacing. For example, on one graph I get one tick at 15 and another at 27. On the next one I get one tick at -12 and another at -37 *but something is wrong: the -37 tick is ABOVE the -12 tick!*

My code is as follows:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(themis_data), figsize=(10, 2*len(themis_data)))
for ax, (index, row) in zip(axs, themis_data.iterrows()):
    # Create a series of timestamps at a 1-hour cadence between the start and stop times
    date_range = pd.date_range(start=row['Date_Start'], end=row['Date_Stop']+pd.Timedelta(days=1)-pd.Timedelta(seconds=1), freq='1h')
    # Return all the values that correspond to these timestamps
    filtered_dst_values = DST_filtered.loc[DST_filtered['Date'].isin(date_range), 'DST']

    #For some reason, if there is no data then fill all 0
    if len(filtered_dst_values) == 0:
        filtered_dst_values = pd.Series([0] * len(date_range))

    # Plot the returned values
    ax.plot(date_range, filtered_dst_values)

    #Format the axis: set the limits, tick locators, and format for the labels on the x-axis
    ax.set_ylim((-150, 150))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(50))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=2))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Looks like a simple plotting routine, but the output looks like this:
[image]

Edit: here's some sample data:

```
Date_Start,Date_Stop,Y_Start,Y_Stop,X_Max,DST
2011-11-26,2011-12-13,,,,
2012-12-23,2013-01-24,,,,
2014-02-26,2014-03-27,,,,
2015-05-01,2015-05-31,,,,
2016-06-25,2016-07-14,,,,
2017-08-20,2017-09-22,,,,
2018-09-26,2018-11-07,,,,
2019-11-05,2019-12-11,,,,
2020-12-10,2021-01-20,,,,
2022-01-11,2022-03-01,,,,
2023-03-01,2023-04-15,,,,

,DOY,DST,Date
8765,357,12.00,2012-12-22 23:00:00
8766,358,15.00,2012-12-23 00:00:00
8767,358,18.00,2012-12-23 01:00:00
8768,358,15.00,2012-12-23 02:00:00
8769,358,14.00,2012-12-23 03:00:00
8770,358,12.00,2012-12-23 04:00:00
8771,358,11.00,2012-12-23 05:00:00
8772,358,13.00,2012-12-23 06:00:00
8773,358,16.00,2012-12-23 07:00:00
8774,358,17.00,2012-12-23 08:00:00
8775,358,16.00,2012-12-23 09:00:00
8776,358,14.00,2012-12-23 10:00:00
8777,358,14.00,2012-12-23 11:00:00
8778,358,15.00,2012-12-23 12:00:00
8779,358,12.00,2012-12-23 13:00:00
8780,358,7.00,2012-12-23 14:00:00
8781,358,5.00,2012-12-23 15:00:00
8782,358,4.00,2012-12-23 16:00:00
8783,358,4.00,2012-12-23 17:00:00
8784,358,6.00,2012-12-23 18:00:00
8785,358,9.00,2012-12-23 19:00:00
8786,358,12.00,2012-12-23 20:00:00
8787,358,13.00,2012-12-23 21:00:00
8788,358,14.00,2012-12-23 22:00:00
8789,358,16.00,2012-12-23 23:00:00
8790,359,20.00,2012-12-24 00:00:00
8791,359,21.00,2012-12-24 01:00:00
8792,359,16.00,2012-12-24 02:00:00
8793,359,13.00,2012-12-24 03:00:00
8794,359,12.00,2012-12-24 04:00:00
8795,359,14.00,2012-12-24 05:00:00
8796,359,16.00,2012-12-24 06:00:00
8797,359,16.00,2012-12-24 07:00:00
8798,359,16.00,2012-12-24 08:00:00
8799,359,13.00,2012-12-24 09:00:00
8800,359,12.00,2012-12-24 10:00:00
8801,359,13.00,2012-12-24 11:00:00
8802,359,17.00,2012-12-24 12:00:00
8803,359,17.00,2012-12-24 13:00:00
8804,359,17.00,2012-12-24 14:00:00
8805,359,12.00,2012-12-24 15:00:00
8806,359,6.00,2012-12-24 16:00:00
8807,359,2.00,2012-12-24 17:00:00
8808,359,2.00,2012-12-24 18:00:00
8809,359,5.00,2012-12-24 19:00:00
8810,359,8.00,2012-12-24 20:00:00
8811,359,9.00,2012-12-24 21:00:00
8812,359,10.00,2012-12-24 22:00:00
8813,359,12.00,2012-12-24 23:00:00
```

You can modify the date ranges, for example
`2012-12-23,2012-12-24,,,,`

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: Added some data. Since it's tens of thousands of points long, I've added a snippet that falls between the second date range.

Comment: The problem is probably that your y-values are strings, not numbers.  Did you read the csv files with `pd.read_csv()`?  Try `DST_filtered['DST'] = DST_filtered['DST'].astype(float)` to force them numeric.

Comment: What packages are you using? Can you provide the full code?